# Can't make regex match desired input in HTML form

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

So here is what I tried so far :

```js
required pattern=' +  ' "[A-Za-z0-9 .,!?:\[\]()\"-+]+"  '   +'class
```

Note that I've used 's because I generate all of this "dynamically" through JS.
It only validates one letter for some reason, like any of the symbols individually are OK, but it doesn't validate anything with 2 or more characters.
For example it correctly validates "c" but not "ca" even though I have a "+" after the last ].

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var pattern = new RegExp("[A-Za-z0-9 .,!?:\\[\\]()\"\\-+]+");
console.log( pattern );
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, all I had to do to make it work was replace the "s with 's, like that:  required pattern=' +  '\'[A-Za-z0-9 .,!?:\\[\\]()\"\\-+]+\''   +'class

Comment: My englis bad can understd